M1 Chip Workarounds For Biobakery Suite Conda Install of Metaphlan / Blast?
I'm trying to setup the biobakery suite of tools for processing my data and am currently stuck on being unable to install Metaphlan due to a BLAST dependency and (to my understanding) there not being a bioconda/conda/mini-forge wrapper(?) for installing BLAST when you're using a computer with an arm M1 (Mac chip) processor.
I'm new to using conda, and I've gotten so far as to manually download blast from NCIB (https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/executables/blast+/LATEST/), but I can't figure out how to get the conda environment to recognize where it is and to be able to utilize it in order to finish the metaphlan install. At first I thought it might go in the pkgs_dir, but it doesn't look like the other packages and there isn't an associated conda file obviously.
To further help visualize my point:
(metaphlan) ➜  ~ conda install bioconda::metaphlan
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - anaconda
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides blast >=2.6.0 needed by metaphlan-2.8.1-py_0
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible
└─ metaphlan is not installable because there are no viable options
   ├─ metaphlan [2.8.1|3.0|...|4.0.6] would require
   │  └─ blast >=2.6.0 , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
   └─ metaphlan [4.1.0|4.1.1] would require
└─ r-compositions, which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel).

Note: I also already tried using brew to install the biobakery suite, hoping that would somehow magically circumvent the issue by avoiding the conda channels and then I could just update Metaphlan2 to Metaphlan4 after initial install and avoid all this, but that returns errors with counter.txt files, which I haven't otherwise dug into. Example:
Error: biobakery_tool_suite: Failed to download resource "strainphlan--counter" 
Download failed: https://bitbucket.org/biobakery/metaphlan2/downloads/strainphlan_homebrew_counter.txt

